# Retrieve column value using column name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SSMS 2014, I want to retrieve column value using column name in SQL Server. The user can select any column from the table and retrieve the value of that column.

**Example:**

```
exec employee Name 'karl'
```

**Output as follows:**

```
| Id | Name | ManagerId | ManagerName | Gender | Dept |
| 5  | Karl |   1       | Luke        |   M    |  1   |
```

I am creating procedure to resolve this but i am not getting any value in output.

```
Create proc sp_getEmpDetail
    @colname varchar(50),
    @colvalue varchar(50)
as
    Select * 
    from employees1 
    where @colname = @colvalue
```

I am not getting any value in output.

When I am debugging it then variables are getting value which I supplied.

Please help to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an example of the technique near the bottom of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091505/sql-server-reference-a-column-by-name-in-agrregate-function).

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
--for this you need to create a dynamic Query

Create proc sp_getEmpDetail
@colname varchar(50),
@colvalue varchar(50)
AS
    DECLARE @Sql_String NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @Sql_String='Select * from employees1  where '+@colname+' = '''+@colvalue+''''
    PRINT @Sql_String
    EXEC(@Sql_String)
END
```

Comment: Yep, you beat me.

Comment: @wallyk Thanks for appreciation